# stripe.error.InvalidRequestError: Request req_cB2yR3ogZdAH28: You cannot use a Stripe token more than once: tok_1FH9IqEoM5FutsBDcB1o0hYN

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

i am receiving the following TypeError error message:

```
stripe.error.InvalidRequestError
stripe.error.InvalidRequestError: Request req_cB2yR3ogZdAH28: You cannot use a Stripe token more than once: tok_1FH9IqEoM5FutsBDcB1o0hYN.
```

attempting to follow follow [stripe documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/api/cards/create) but newbie to python following outdated tutorial on Udemy but really want/ need this app to work. Any idea or solutions welcome! Thank you in advance

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import render
import stripe

stripe.api_key = settings.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY

# Create your views here.

@login_required
def checkout(request):
    publishkey = settings.STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY
    customer_id = request.user.userstripe.stripe_id
    if request.method == 'POST':
        token = request.POST['stripeToken']
        # Create a charge: this will charge the customer's card

        stripe.Charge.create(
            amount=499,
            currency='usd',
            source=token,
            description='Example charge',
        )

        stripe.Customer.create_source(
            customer_id,
            source=token
        )
    context = {'publishkey': publishkey}
    template = 'checkout.html'
    return render(request, template, context)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what that error is referring to, but that `customer` variable will be of type `Source` rather than `Customer`, as you're retrieving a source. So when you create your charge you'll be passing in the wrong id for `customer`. Why not just use the `customer_id` you retrieved earlier?

Comment: I am a newbie to python can you please show an example? I've made changes to my code and am now receive yet another error message "stripe.error.InvalidRequestError: Request req_cB2yR3ogZdAH28: You cannot use a Stripe token more than once: tok_1FH9IqEoM5FutsBDcB1o0hYN." I'm attempting to follow Stripe's documentation because the tutorial i am using is outdate.

Comment: That error means you've already used that token and it has been consumed. You'll have to create a new token via Elements on your client.